# Replace string only if its not followed with left square brackets i.e. [

Tags: javascript, regex

[Javascript] I want to replace string only if its not followed with left hand square brackets i.e. [

e.g.1  if string is "ABCD[" then it should not replace,as string followed with left square bracket

e.g.2  if string is "ABC" then it should replace with target string, as string not followed with left square bracket.

e.g. 3 if string is "ABCD ABCD[", here it should replace first word only.

**Below code which I have used:**

```
var val = "ABC";
var find = val+"(?!\[)";
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
var inputstring = "ABC[";
var replacewith = "PQR";
inputstring = inputstring.replace(re,replacewith);

// Getting Error as :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /ABC(?![)/: Unterminated character class
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for this:

```
/ABC(?!\[)/
```

OR in general match any word that is not followed by `[`:

```
/\b\w+\b(?!\[)/
```

`(?!\[)` is negative lookahead that avoids this match if next character is `[`.

Comment: I have used but not working...added example above..plz suggest

Comment: In `RegExp` it should be: `var find = val+"(?!\\[)";` with double esapes.

Comment: This does not work in general. "test[".match(/\w+(?!\\[)/) returns "tes" while it should return no match (because the word test is followed by [ thus should be excluded)

Comment: Use `/\b\w+\b(?!\[)/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
 ABCD(?!\[)
```

http://regex101.com/r/eH1hR8/1

Note, that the modifiers `gm` are just set for demonstration purpose. You don't need them, unless you have a multiline string and want to replace ALL occurences.

Comment: I have added example above....getting error as unterminated character class..pls suggest.